# LWJGL Slick Java OS X Natives

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm trying to make a jar out of my game written with LWJGL and Slick. My technique is to extract the natives out of the jar into a temporary directory and then change the org.lwjgl.librarypath to the folder with the extracted files. Sadly this doesn't work on OS X... on Windows it runs fine, but on Mac it doesn't find "liblwjgl.dylib", which is actually not existing...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /var/folders/r0/qwm413fs3b9djwyb0d4pwhn40000gr/T/wo42/natives/liblwjgl.dylib
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1828)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:70)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)
    at org.alternativedev.wo42.Game.run(Game.java:136)
    at org.alternativedev.wo42.App.run(App.java:32)
    at org.alternativedev.wo42.App.main(App.java:23)
```

Has anyone already had the same problem and/or knows the solution?

BigTeddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in order for the jar to work you also need the native files. There is a tool called [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice) that can allow you to put the natives inside your jars.

Comment: But my System is working on Windows... why doesn't it work on OS X?

Comment: Okay the Problem was, that i had the 1.7 VM Beta installed, which let my programm crash

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028507/libgdx-project-cant-load-library-liblwjgl-dylib). Essentially, you need to soft-link `liblwjgl.jnilib` from the natives dir to `liblwjgl.dylib`. That did it for me.