# libGDX project can't load library liblwjgl.dylib

Tags: java, macos, libgdx

A new libGDX project can't load the library liblwjgl.dylib when running the desktop project.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: 
/var/folders/4l/nsj9j4xj51g8h_6y_ndpnmc80000gn/T/libgdxChristian/3741154320/liblwjgl.dylib
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1798)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1080)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:70)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.<clinit>(AL.java:59)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.openal.OpenALAudio.<init>(OpenALAudio.java:70)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:80)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:64)
    at com.foxhat.test.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

**Update:**

I'm running `Java 1.8` on OSX 10.9. The same error appears not only with an own project, but also with foreign JARs built with libGDX.

The folder mentioned in the error, where `liblwjgl.dylib` is searched, contains:

```
liblwjgl.jnilib
openal.dylib
```

Renaming `liblwjgl.jnilib` to `.dylib` **does** work for the foreign application, but not for my own.

Comment: When I started libgdx, I made a mistake when I tried to run the "core" project instead of the desktop project, I think I had the same issue, and it usually works fine to use the gdx-setup-ui to start a new project.

Comment: I had the exact same issue and that little renaming trick you suggested did it for me. If you are someone who happened on this question, give this a spin just to make sure.

Comment: Thanks for the mention of renaming the .jnilib to .dylib.  This worked for me!  I'm using Hiero for SDF font rendering with https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-bmfont-text

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a compatibility issue between Java 7 and LWJGL. For some reason, this also only affects OS X, as it works just fine on both my Windows and Ubuntu machines, but not my Mac. Your options to work with until the problem is fixed:

- Debug on Android / Robovm
- Code on another machine until the problem is fixed

Considering you can use an Android emulator, I think Android testing is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try including the LWJGL .jar library into the source path, or the "core" directory.